# Nesting subordinate clauses immediately one after the other

Tags: subordinate-clauses

Is this construction allowed in English? The relevant part is set in bold:

"This is especially vital for technology companies such as Google or Apple, **that, while** they are in fierce competition with each other, strive to create islands of cooperation and creativity within their organisation to create a climate conducive to innovation."

The question is: Can you introduce a second subordinate clause immediately after another one?

If this is not allowed or considered bad style, is there another way instead of rearranging the sentence in the following way (and reversing the logical order):

"This is especially vital for technology companies such as Google or Apple, **tha**t strive to create islands of cooperation and creativity within their organisation to create a climate conducive to innovation, **while** they are in fierce competition with each other."

Thanks!

Comment: I see no problem with this construction, and use something like it almost every day.  Though, for an official answer, I will defer to an expert who, though a stranger to me, I trust to answer more authoritatively.

Comment: There either needs to be a comma before _such as Google_, or no comma after _Apple_. _That_ begins a restrictive relative clause, and not a non-restrictive one, which the comma would mark. _.. companies such as Google or Apple that, while .. each other, strive to .._ That construction's allowed in English. But be careful of using commas before relative clauses starting with _that_. _Which_ can swing both ways, but _that_ only appears in restrictive relative clauses.

Comment: Sounds okay, to me. The comma before *that* is needed to help readers figure out that the relative clause goes with *technology companies*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the correct *[punctuation](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/commas.asp)*, both constructions are appropriate:

> *This is especially vital for technology companies, such as Google or Apple, that, **while they are in fierce competition with each other**,
>   strive to create islands of cooperation and creativity within their
>   organisation to create a climate conducive to innovation.*

Makes essentially the same point as:

> *This is especially vital for technology companies, such as Google or Apple, that strive to create islands of cooperation and creativity within their
>   organisation to create a climate conducive to innovation, **while they are in fierce competition with each other**.*

---

With the commas in place, [*such as*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/such-as?q=such%20as) identifies *Google* and *Apple* as specific examples of *technology companies that strive to create islands of cooperation and creativity*.

The restrictive [relative clause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_relative_clauses#): *that strive to create islands of cooperation and creativity within their organisation to create a climate conducive to innovation*, is embedded in the independent clause, and it identifies what kind of *technology companies* are being discussed. It is also a *[matrix clause](http://grammar.about.com/od/mo/g/matrixclauseterm.htm)*, because an adverbial subordinate clause is embedded in it.

The conjunction *while* embeds an adverbial subordinate clause within the restrictive clause. The subordinate adverbial clause modifies *strive* with the concurrent state of being: *are in competition*. A subordinate clause can be positioned before or after the main verb of the matrix clause, depending on the desired emphasis.

---

[While](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/While) communicates that *strive to create* is **concurrent** with *are in fierce competition,* so the order of the phrases has no impact on the logic of contrasting them.

> The primary function of [while] as a conjunction is to indicate that
>   two separate clauses occur at the same time.

Deciding which construction makes your point more effectively is a matter of style, which ELU doesn't address, but your *climate* metaphor has potential. Since an internal climate of cooperation is being contrasted with an external climate of competition:

> *This is especially vital for technology companies, such as Google or Apple, that **cooperate** in a climate of creative innovation within their organisations, while **competing** fiercely against each other.*

---

www.grammarbook.com

en.wikipedia.org

Comment: perhaps you could add an explanation of the relationship between the clauses.