# scope of subordinate clauses

Tags: conditionals, subordinate-clauses

I have a complex sentence with multiple subordinate clauses: Can one subordinate clause encapsulate another or is each subordinate clause equal and independent to each other:

I will go running when it is sunny outside only if I feel energetic.

Does the "Only if I feel energetic" place a condition on everything before it "I will go running when it is sunny outside" or does it only place a condition on the nearest subject and verb which is "it is sunny outside"? My guess is the former but I would appreciate any explanation as to why the latter case is not true.

Comment: Pragmatics plays a substantial part in the decoding of English sentences. One is left puzzled why 'I will go running only if I feel energetic' or 'I will go running only when it is sunny and only if I feel energetic' is not used. One is trying to envisage a situation where 'I _always_ go running when it is not sunny; however,' is the immediate prior context.

Comment: The natural interpretation is that you will go running in sunny conditions provided you feel energetic.

Comment: 1 *This is the cat that killed the rat that ate the corn that was in the barn that was next to the house that Jack built.* 2 *Some people claim that Ancient Egyptians, who certainly had a good knowledge of navigation that was probably learned from the Phoenicians, visited America.* 3 There is no “encapsulation” in your example: *{I will go running} Main Clause {when it is sunny outside} Subordinate clause **but** {only if I feel energetic.} equal subordinate clause.* Both clauses modify the main clause independently.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/232618/nesting-subordinate-clauses-immediately-one-after-the-other

Comment: @Greybeard "I will go running" is **not** the main clause, but simply part of a larger clause. The main (matrix) clause is the sentence as a whole. The subordinate clauses are embedded in, and thus part of, the main clause.

Comment: @BillJ you will note the terms that the OP uses: They are not as precise as you might have wished - I used those.

Comment: The OP didn't state what they thought was the main clause. In any case, learners commonly make the mistake of stripping out the sub clauses and then claiming  that what remains is the main clause. It isn't -- what remains is just part of the main clause.